# Editing files in samba directly using Linux?

Tags: visual-studio-code, samba

I have a samba host computer where the remote files are located. I want to edit those files from my laptop without copying them first just like on windows. I am using VS Code on Ubuntu and same on Windows, both OS in dual-boot. I am in process of transitioning my workspace to Linux but the problem is that I can't edit files directly because VS Code won't display samba mount points. I figured out "gedit" can achieve the editing directly but who uses that as a code editor?

I am looking for a service or application that allows me to mount the samba shares in the way that VS Code can see it and be able to edit directly from it. I don't know any keywords to find the solution to my problem so any help would save me time.

Comment: I guess you are looking for this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/712290/mount-smb-share-with-gvfs-from-command-line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question

It turns out that I just had to install this package:

> gvfs-fuse

Now i can edit files directly to my samba share regardless of what application I use.